# run length encoding compressing

Tags: java

So the point of this code is to compress a string and if it occurs more than 3 times, add a "# + number of occurence". For a letter the format is (#num)(letter) for a number value, they both have "#".

for example, if i have yyyy77777 the output would be #4y#5#7 
but my problem is it doesn't print the number values with "#" in front of it, so my output it $4y#57

another problem i have is that when it's less than 3, it just prints the same. so i.e.: nnnnnff should have an output of #5nff
but my code turns it into #5n2f

any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Compress {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.next();
    String compressString = compress(s);
    System.out.println(compressString);

}
public static String compress (String original){
    String str = "";
   // int n = (Integer) null;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<original.length()-1; i++){

        if(original.charAt(i) == original.charAt(i+1)){
            count++;
            if(i == original.length()-2){
                if(count == 1){
                    str = str + original.charAt(i);
                }
                //if count is equal or greater than 3, print with #
                else if (count >= 3) {
                    str = str + "#" + count +  original.charAt(i);
                }          
                else{
                    str = str + original.charAt(i);
                }                    
            }
        }
        else{
            if(count == 1){
                if(i == original.length() - 2){
                    str = str + original.charAt(i);
                    str = str + original.charAt(i+1);
                }
                else{
                str = str + original.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(i == original.length() - 2){
                    str = str + count + original.charAt(i);
                    str = str + original.charAt(i+1);
                }
                else{
                    str = str +"#"+ count + original.charAt(i);
                }


            }

            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Martha! You should leave your question like it was when Sweeper answered it, so it can help other people in the future. The "check mark" that you applied to his/her answer is enough to show that the answer was helpful and solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently treating digits and non-digits the exact same way. To fix your code, you just need to add if statements to check if the characters are digits.

You can add the if statements just before you append a `#(count)(character)` to the result.

Replace this line (there are two lines like this! Replace both of them):

```
str = str + "#" + count +  original.charAt(i);
```

with

```
if (Character.isDigit(original.charAt(i))) {
    str = str + "#" + count + "#" + original.charAt(i);
} else {
    str = str + "#" + count +  original.charAt(i);
}
```

Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
public static String compress (String original){
    String str = "";
    int count = 0;
    char currentChar = original.charAt(0);
    for(int i=0; i<original.length(); i++){
        if (currentChar == original.charAt(i)) { // count it if this not a new character
            currentChar = original.charAt(i);
            count++;
        } else { // if we have encountered a new character
            if (count > 2) { // and we have already counted 2 or more of the previous char
                if (Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                    str += "#" + count + "#" + currentChar;
                } else {
                    str += "#" + count + currentChar;
                }
            } else if (count == 2) { // if we have only counted two of the previous char
                str += currentChar;
                str += currentChar;
            } else if (count == 1) { // if we have only counted one of the previous char
                str += currentChar;
            }
            currentChar = original.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    // treat the end of the string as a new char
    if (count > 2) {
        if (Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
            str += "#" + count + "#" + currentChar;
        } else {
            str += "#" + count + currentChar;
        }
    } else if (count == 2) {
        str += currentChar;
        str += currentChar;
    } else if (count == 1) {
        str += currentChar;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: i totally forgot about the ".isDigit()" function, thank you so much!!

Comment: im still having a bit trouble figuring out how to keep a string i.e. "abbc" to output "abbc". right now my code outputs "a2bc" i think it has to do with my nested if/else loops but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @MarthaN. I can't really follow your code, but I have edited to include my own solution. Does it help?

Comment: yes! another quick addition - if i wanted my output to say, have 3 lines i.e.:  bbbb888 (newline) jkjjjjjnnnn (newline) 0003nn, how would i go about printing that?

Comment: @MarthaN. Note that it is discouraged to edit out the whole question after it has been answered. This is not beneficial to future visitors. Someone has already rolled back the edit. Your additional question should be asked in a new post. Please do some searching on Google first, then come back and post another question. Your question is quite unclear at the moment. What do you mean by "how would i go about printing that"? Can't you use `System.out.println`?  Be sure to describe in detail what you are having trouble with when posting a new question.

Comment: @MarthaN. That's a different question. Please look that up on Google first, then create another post for that.